# Mutliple offsets with indexed VBOs in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, vbo

I've got two VBOs, one full of data, the other full of indices into this data. Both are concatenations of distinct meshes. Is there a way to draw these things in such a format?

Visually:

```
Each [] denotes a mesh
Vertex VBO: [  vertex data ][  vertex data ][  vertex data ]
Index  VBO: [indices into ^][indices into ^][indices into ^]
```

Is there some way to specify offsets into the array of indices as well as the array of vertices? All the data has the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a VBO is bound glVertexAttribPointer (and also the legacy gl…Pointer) functions do take a byte offset as their "data" parameter. Instead of casting the number to `void*` I suggest you cast the function signature to taking an `uintptr_t` (found in stdint.h), which is what actually should happen.

In the same way you can offset into the index array with glDrawElements: If there's a index buffer bound it takes a byte offset into the buffer.

Another approach would be using [glDrawElementsBaseVertex](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElementsBaseVertex.xml).

Comment: Yeah I was looking into glDrawElementsBaseVertex, but I didn't know exactly how to set it up for my situation. Could you give an example? Thanks.